# How to design hamburger menu-links in a responsive navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to design my hamburger menu-links but can not find the correct way to do it.

The example I am looking at: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav

I think the problem is that I have added ul class="headerlinks" to design the full screen menu. Does anyone have a solution?

[image]

I want to display it like in w3schools example:
[image]

**Here is my code**

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += "responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
.topnav {
 background-color: white;
 width: 100%;
 position:absolute;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-bottom: 1px solid;
 border-bottom-color: #e8ebef;
 height: 120px;
}

.topnav a {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 color: #4d4d4f;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 17px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.topnav a:active{
 color: #bed017;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
 }

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}


.headerlinks{
 margin-left: 25%;
 margin-top: 1.5%;
 
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
   
  .topnav  a{display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }  

  .circle
    {
        display: none;
    }

 .signInbtn
 {
  display: block !important;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  } 
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
 <img class="headerlogo" src=""></img>
 
 <ul class="headerlinks">
  <a href="#home">Hem</a>
  <a href="#">test</a>
  <a href="#newcustomer">Ny kund</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:20px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
 </ul>
 
 <ul>
  <li class="headerLogIn">
   <a><button class="circle" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'">LOGGAIN</button></a>
  </li>
 </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please explain what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got a typo in the function where you append the responsive class names (You have missed adding a space before the 'responsive' class name). Your function should be :

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

So, the line :

```
x.className += "responsive";
```

should be:

```
x.className += " responsive";
```

Adding that space should fix the issue. Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: This helps, but there are errors in the html structure (like ul without list items). I recommend a fresh start and look at the w3c example, after that if there are any problems, we will try to help again.